# Enforcing independence of time to event and censoring time in survival analysis

Tags: survival, independence, censoring

I am studying survival analysis and reading Tutz & Schmid ["Modeling Discrete Time-to-Event Data"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-28158-2) (2016). The authors often consider the censoring time $C$ to be independent of the time to event of interest (e.g. failure) $T$. At the same time they occasionally suggest each of $T$ and $C$ could be modelled using e.g. a logistic discrete hazard model, potentially using the same covariates $\mathbf{X}$. I do not see that this would enforce the independence of the model-implied $C$ and $T$.

What are some survival models and/or estimation methods that enforce the assumed independence between $C$ and $T$?

Comment: The question is kind of broad, but this is because I am new to the survival literature. Sorry if it happens to be a duplicate.

Comment: They are speaking of assessing systematic patterns of follow-up time for different types (at baseline) of subjects.  By examining $C$ vs. $X$ they are avoiding a discussion of $C$ vs. $T$ which is an unverifiable assumption as you don't observed failure time for censored observations.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, while the assumption is unverifiable, it would be nice if it were used consistently in all steps of a problem (or not used at all). I find it uncomfortable to make an assumption in step 1 but disregard it in step 2. It is my impression this is what is happening, or am I mistaken?

Comment: That's not the way I'd interpret their work.  Looking at $C$ vs. $X$ is trying to address a different question.  It's not that $C$ vs. $T$ is any less important.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, yes, I realize that $C$ vs. $\mathbf{X}$ is a different question, but it is not my concern. My concern is that $C$ is assumed to be independent of $T$ when deriving some results such as the likelihood of $T$ (and also the likelihood of $C$). Yet this is not enforced in modelling $T$ and $C$ later on. If we do not enforce that, how can we trust the likelihoods of $T$ and $C$ taken separately?

Comment: What do you mean by "enforce"?  The independence of censoring and impending risk of failure is a fundamental assumption for everything we do.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, e.g. in linear regression models estimated by OLS, $X$ is assumed to be uncorrelated with $\varepsilon$. This is enforced by the OLS estimator so that $\hat\varepsilon \perp X$. This is roughly what I mean by *enforce an assumption*.

Comment: I think we're arguing about semantics (which doesn't make it less important).  Assumptions that are not currently stated are still "enforced" (minor point).

Comment: Related: ["Survival: treat censoring as a competing risk and use multinomial logit"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591877/survival-treat-censoring-as-a-competing-risk-and-use-multinomial-logit).