# Simulating and estimating generalized mixed effects models: how to avoid convergence problems?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, survival, simulation

**Basic generalized mixed effects**
I am simulating data from a generalized mixed effects model
$$
P(y_{it}=1\mid x_{it})=h(\delta_0+\alpha_i+\beta_t+\gamma x_{it})
$$
where the dependent variable is binary, $y_{it}\in\{0,1\}$, and where the inverse link function is logistic, $h(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$. I set $\alpha_1=\beta_1=0$ for identifiability.

I then fit the same model on the simulated data. (Well, not exactly. I do not force $\hat\alpha_1=\hat\beta_1=0$. I think $\hat\beta_1=0$ is forced automatically, though. When R discovers that the model matrix suffers from multicollinearity, it kicks out some terms to get rid of it, and the term corresponding to $\beta_1$ is one of them.) For some configurations of parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, sample size (number of individuals) $n$ and the number of time intervals $q$, I tend to get decent estimation results. For others, I get convergence problems and/or poor estimates.
**Question 1:** What should I tweak in the simulation to avoid convergence problems and to obtain better estimation results?

---

**Generalized mixed effects for modelling survival**
I also try a variation of the same setup. After generating the data, I examine each individual $i=1,\dots,n$ separately. I discard all data points after the first $y_{it}=1$ is recorded. E.g. if $q=5$ and $y_{i,\cdot}=(0,0,1,0,1)$, I discard the last two points and only retain $\tilde y_{i,\cdot}=(0,0,1)$. The subject-matter interpretation is that I am generating survival data where $0$ denotes survival and $1$ denotes death in a given period. Thus the individual above survived the first two time periods and died in the third one. When I try estimating the model based on $\tilde y_{it}$, I *always* get either convergence problems or a perfect fit (or both). I have tried various parameter configurations, but I never got decent estimates.
**Question 2:** What should I tweak in the simulation to avoid convergence problems and to obtain better estimation results?

---

**R code:**

```r
#============================== Simulation

# Set the number of individuals and the number of time periods 
n=100; q=40

# Generate parameter values:
set.seed(1); alphas=runif(n=n  ,min=-1,max=1) #-0.025*q
set.seed(2); betas =runif(n=q  ,min=-1,max=1)
             gamma =1
             delta0=-0.1 # the intercept

# Generate covariate x
set.seed(3); x     =runif(n=n*q,min=-1,max=1); X=matrix(x,nrow=n,byrow=TRUE)

# Specify the desired hazard rates
lambdas=matrix(NA,ncol=q+1,nrow=n)
for(i in 1:n){
 for(t in 1:q){
  lambdas[i,t]=plogis(delta0+alphas[i]+betas[t]+gamma*X[i,t]) # plogis yields a logistic transformation
 }
}; lambdas[,q+1]=1 # by definition
#head(round(lambdas,2))

# Obtain the binary representation of survival
Y=matrix(NA,ncol=q,nrow=n)
for(i in 1:n){
 for(t in 1:q){
  set.seed(n*i+1e6*t); Y[i,t]=rbinom(n=1,size=1,prob=lambdas[i,t])
  #if(Y[i,t]==1) break; # !!! If this line is commented out, we get the basic GLM. Otherwise, we get the survival model !!!
 }
}
y=c(t(Y)) 

# Create identifiers of individual (obj) and time (time)
obj=c(1,rep(0,q-1)); obj=rep(obj,n); obj=cumsum(obj)
time=c(1:q); time=rep(time,n)

# For each individual, delete observations after death
subset=which(!is.na(y)); y=y[subset]; x=x[subset]; obj=obj[subset]; time=time[subset]

# Print out some data
#data=cbind(obj,time,y,x,c(t(lambdas))); head(round(data,2),2*q+2)

#============================== Estimation

# We will use timeout to prevent the calculation from taking forever and R hanging up 
tout=20

# Estimate a random effects (RE) model using `mgcv` package
m1=R.utils::withTimeout( mgcv::gam(y~s(factor(obj),bs="re")+factor(time )+x, family="binomial"), timeout=tout ) 
summary(m1)
delta0_hat1=m1$coef[1]
# How to extact estimates of individual random effects from this model object?
# Extract estimates of time fixed effects
betas_hat1=coef(m1)[2:q]
cor(betas[-1], betas_hat1 )^2
# Plot them against the true parameter values
plot(x=betas[-1],y=unlist(betas_hat1),xlab="true",ylab="fitted",main="Time fixed effects"); abline(a=0,b=1)
# Because of the multicollinearity induced by individual and time effects, the estimates may be biased by a constant.

# Estimate a random effects (RE) model using `lme4` package
m2=R.utils::withTimeout( lme4::glmer(y~(1|obj)+factor(time)+x, family="binomial"), timeout=tout ) 
# This does not converge for me if q=40 but does converge if q=20. You can set q at the top of this script.
summary(m2)
# Extract estimates of individual random effects and time fixed effects
#delta0_hat2=as.numeric(coef(m2)$obj[1,-c(  q+1)]) ???
alphas_hat2=unlist(lme4::ranef(m2))
betas_hat2 =as.numeric(coef(m2)$obj[1,-c(1,q+1)])
cor(alphas   ,alphas_hat2)^2
cor(betas[-1],betas_hat2 )^2
# Plot them against the true parameter values
dev.new(); mar1=c(4,4,3,0.5); par(mfrow=c(2,1),mar=mar1)
 plot(x=alphas    ,y=alphas_hat2,xlab="true",ylab="fitted",main="Individual random effects"); abline(a=0,b=1)
 plot(x=betas[-1] ,y=betas_hat2 ,xlab="true",ylab="fitted",main="Time fixed effects"); abline(a=0,b=1)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
# Because of the multicollinearity induced by individual and time effects, the estimates may be biased by a constant.

# Estimate a fixed effects (FE) model
m3=R.utils::withTimeout( glm(y~factor(obj)+factor(time)+x, family="binomial"), timeout=tout )
summary(m3)
# Extract estimates of individual fixed effects and time fixed effects
delta0_hat3=m3$coef[1]
alphas_hat3=m3$coef[2:n]
betas_hat3 =m3$coef[(n+1):(n+q-1)]
cor(alphas[-1],alphas_hat3)^2
cor(betas[-1] ,betas_hat3 )^2
# Plot them against the true parameter values
dev.new(); mar1=c(4,4,3,0.5); par(mfrow=c(2,1),mar=mar1)
 plot(x=alphas[-1],y=alphas_hat3,xlab="true",ylab="fitted",main="Individual fixed effects"); abline(a=0,b=1)
 plot(x=betas[-1] ,y=betas_hat3 ,xlab="true",ylab="fitted",main="Time fixed effects"); abline(a=0,b=1)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
# Because of the multicollinearity induced by individual and time effects, the estimates may be biased by a constant.
```

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593616

Comment: "For some configurations of parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, sample size (number of individuals) $n$ and the number of time intervals $q$, I tend to get decent estimation results. For others, I get convergence problems and/or poor estimates." Can you be a bit more specific here? When do get convergence problems and/or poor estimates?

Comment: @statmerkur, actually, I have mostly kept $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as they are except for shifting their locations (adding or subtracting up to 2.5). I have also varied $n$ (100, 200, 1000)  and $q$ (10, 20, 40, 100). For quite some combinations I got poor results. If you check out my code with the settings there, models `m1` and `m3` work OK but `m2` fails. For some other combinations, models `m1` and `m3` also fail. And they all fail almost universally if I do survival rather than basic GLM.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer at the moment. But: (i) I *think* if you set `method = "ML"` in `mgcv::gam` the objective functions of  `m1` and `m2` are identical, but different approximations are used to calculate the MLEs; (ii) In the GLM `m3` we have the same issues regarding the model matrix and parameters as in the Q you linked to (but now $\alpha_1=0=\beta_1$). In the GLMMs only $\beta_1=0$ is forced; (iii) The way in which the  $\alpha_i$  are penalized in `mgcv::gam` and `lme4::glmer` is equivalent to assuming that the $\alpha_i$ are (iid) *normal*ly distributed with mean zero...

Comment: ... (iv) the problem when you "discard all data points after the first $y_{it}=1$ is recorded" is probably complete separation, which you could double-check with the `detectseparation` package.

Comment: @statmerkur, thank you a lot for your helpful comments! I hope you could find some time for posting an answer within the next week, then you could get the bounty. Regarding (ii), I suppose you are right. But this time my issue is poor convergence rather than trouble recovering the true coefficients. Regarding (iii), again I am worried about convergence first, but I should definitely pay attention to this detail and try simulations with a normal distribution. Regarding (iv), I was suspecting this might be the case, but I just am not sure how to design a simulation that avoids that...

Comment: Hmm... maybe I am missing out something but what I don't see is sample size calculations. So using something like [`simr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simr/index.html). I would simplistically assume that underpowered models are much less likely to be estimated correctly/converge.

Comment: @usεr11852, are you suggesting to increase $n$? Or perhaps $q$? Or both? I have tried several combinations of these as specified in a comment above but I did not notice that changing one or the other would tend to help. But that does not mean that cannot help, of course.

Comment: I suggest it mostly to avoid searching configurations we would expect to be underpowered. It will also allow us to explore "smaller" sample sizes and save computational time.

Comment: @usεr11852, so how do I find out which configurations might be underpowered without trying them out? I have been doing simulations (manually, i.e. without using the package you suggested) without much luck. Is there a theoretical argument I can use?

Comment: I would use one of the models who I like and converged and then do a power-analysis on it.

Comment: @usεr11852, OK, I see. None of the models has converged in the case of survival (my question 2), though, so that will not help there. But it is surely a thing to consider. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Question 1

There are a few things to say here. First of random effect coefficients are supposed to be (multivariate)normal.
So(keeping the variance the same) you should write: `set.seed(1); alphas=rnorm(n=n, sd = sqrt(1/3))`
Source(among many) the original lme4-Paper, page 2: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5823.pdf

But fixing this does not remove your convergence problem so i looked at the GLMM-FAQ(https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#convergence-warnings) which points to the R-command `?convergence`(only works if you have `lme4` loaded)

### What actually is your Problem

Keeping your code as is the convergence warning on m2 is:

> optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 4 (failure to converge in 10000 evaluations)
> Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00857345 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
> failure to converge in 10000 evaluations

0.0085 is pretty close to the tolerance of 0.002 and checking the Hessian as instructed by `?convergence` reveals no major deviations:

```
if (isLMM(m2)) {
  pars <- getME(m2,"theta")
} else {
  ## GLMM: requires both random and fixed parameters
  pars <- getME(m2, c("theta","fixef"))
}
if (require("numDeriv")) {
  cat("hess:\n"); print(hess <- hessian(devfun, unlist(pars)))
  cat("grad:\n"); print(grad <- grad(devfun, unlist(pars)))
  cat("scaled gradient:\n")
  print(scgrad <- solve(chol(hess), grad))
}
## compare with internal calculations:
m2@optinfo$derivs
summary(m2@optinfo$derivs$Hessian - hess)
```

So just keep the fitting process running for more than 10,000 steps and you get there:

```
m2_restart <- update(m2, start=getME(m2, c("theta","fixef"))) #continues fitting from the m2 parameters
m2_restart@optinfo$feval # 1692 steps
summary(m2_restart)
```

You might need multiple restarts, make sure to use the latest model sor the new start-parameters. Weirdly enough running it in one step did **not** work (I took the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19479820/7840119). But it actaully self-stopped at just over 12,000 iterations with the warnig-code of "ok".

```
m2_long <- glmer(y~(1|obj)+factor(time)+x, family="binomial", control = glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun = 30000)))
```

#### Why?

Your model is basically well specified and identifiable, but the huge number of coefficients and the low informational value of a binary response create a very large region of fairly flat likelihood that posses a considerable challenge to numerical optimization. This can also pretty unpredictable.

#### How to fix this

I can think of multiple "solutions":

1. Ignore it and just accept the slight deviation from the true ML-estimator. The coefficients between m2 and m2_restart only differ by 0.02.Of course fitting 10,000 iterations almost everytime is slow
2. Embrace the slowness and fit to completion every time.
3. Simplify and here i actually have two ideas:

a) You can use a simpler approximation of the likelihood by setting the `nAGQ` parameter to 0:

```
m2_simplified <-  glmer(y~(1|obj)+factor(time)+x, family="binomial", verbose = 1, nAGQ = 0) # fitted in just 19 steps
summary(m2_simplified)
```

Check `help("glmer")` for what that actually means

b) If you don't like having your $\alpha$ being normal than you can use a conditional logit model. The downside is, that it doesn't "care" about estimating the $\alpha$ correctly, but it does respect the stratification:

```
library(survival) 
m4 <- clogit(y ~ strata(obj)+factor(time)+x)
summary(m4)
```

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_logistic_regression

## Question 2

If you only look at each object until it "dies", you have one observation per object. It's survival time. This means that frequentist methods can't estimate any object-level effects. You sometimes have observation level random effects in over dispersed counting data, but those are basically just data-transformations and don't apply here.

You could maybe accomplish something by utilizing strong priors in `stan_glmer` but i will warn you: The `rstanarm`-Package takes a long time to install and fitting models with stan is very computationally expensive.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It includes quite a few useful pointers and ideas. Regarding Q1, for starters it is encouraging to learn that *Your model is basically well specified and identifiable*. What I am looking for is sets of parameter values (including sample size and number of time periods) that would make convergence easier, if that is at all possible. Regarding Q2, I am following [Tutz & Schmid (2016)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-28158-2) chapter 9 on mixed effects survival models. So are you sure that frequentist methods can't estimate any object-level effects?

Comment: The logic of *If you only look at each object until it "dies", you have one observation per object. This means that frequentist methods can't estimate any object-level effects.* is very appealing. Yet I am reluctant to conclude that an entire chapter of an otherwise sensible textbook by seemingly expert authors is nonsense. I wonder what is missing here...

Comment: I meant I am reluctant to conclude it right away, as I suspect there might be other reasons behind the problem. I did not mean to say I would never do it.

Comment: Sorry i accidently hit enter and then got stuck editing, I'm still looking at frailty models

Comment: It is of course sensible to not discount a reputable source over my Statements. I have looked at a variety of sources about frailty in survival models but i can't find anything that is on the individual level. for Example here there is this https://data.princeton.edu/pop509/frailtyr but all the moms in their data had multiple kids. Sadly i don't have access to Trutz and Schmidt right now, but perhaps their REs had some structure to them as well.

Comment: Hm, I might simply have misinterpreted what I read in the book. I should take another look!