# Simulating and estimating a mixed effects model: poor estimates of time fixed effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, estimation, simulation, fixed-effects-model

I am simulating data from a basic mixed effects model
$$
y_{it}=\alpha_i+\beta_t+\gamma x_{it}+\varepsilon_{it}.
$$
I then estimate a corresponding fixed effects model on the simulated data. I get good estimates for individual fixed effects but poor estimates for time fixed effects. Why could that be?

(Actually, the estimates of fixed effects are all biased. I am not worried about that as I think the location is not identified.)

[image]

---

**R code:**

```r
#---------- Simulation

# Set the number of individuals and the number of time periods: 
n=100; T=100

# Generate parameter values:
set.seed(1); alphas=runif(n=n,min=-1,max=1)
set.seed(2); betas =runif(n=T,min=-1,max=1)
             gamma =1

# Generate covariate x and error term eps
set.seed(3); x     =rnorm(n=n*T); X  =matrix(x  ,nrow=n,byrow=TRUE)
set.seed(4); eps   =rnorm(n=n*T); Eps=matrix(eps,nrow=n,byrow=TRUE)

# Obtain the dependent variable y
Y=matrix(NA,ncol=T,nrow=n)
for(i in 1:n){
 for(t in 1:T){
  Y[i,t]=alphas[i]+betas[t]+gamma*X[i,t]+Eps[i,t]
 }
}
y=c(t(Y))

# Create identifiers of individuals (obj) and time periods (time)
obj =c(1,rep(0,T-1)); obj =rep(obj,n); obj =cumsum(obj)
time=c(1:T); time=rep(time,n)

#---------- Fixed effects estimation

# Estimate by accounting for the individual heterogeneity using a FE model
m3=lm(y~-1+factor(obj)+factor(time)+x)
summary(m3)
# Extract estimates of individual and time fixed effects
alphas_hat3=m3$coef[1:n]
betas_hat3 =m3$coef[(n+1):(n+T)]
cor(alphas,alphas_hat3)^2
cor(betas, betas_hat3 )^2
# Plot them against the true parameter values
dev.new(); mar1=c(4,4,3,0.5); par(mfrow=c(2,1),mar=mar1)
 plot(x=alphas,y=alphas_hat3,xlab="true",ylab="fitted",main="Individual fixed effects"); abline(a=0,b=1)
 plot(x=betas ,y=betas_hat3 ,xlab="true",ylab="fitted",main="Time fixed effects"      ); abline(a=0,b=1)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, the columns of the design matrix of `m3` would be linearly dependent since the sum of the column vectors identifying the objects and the sum of the the column vectors identifying the time points both equal $\mathbf{1}_{n\cdot T}$. However,  `lm` calls `model.matrix` internally, which in turn drops one column$-$in this case the one indicating time point 1$-$to generate a design matrix of full column rank. But this means that `m3` contains the estimated coefficients of a model without $\beta_1$ (i.e., in which $\beta_1$ is forced to equal zero).
The new parameters in terms of the original parameters are given by
$$
\tilde{\alpha}_i = \alpha_i + \beta_1 \;\;\forall\, i \in \left\{1,\ldots,n\right\},\\
\tilde{\beta}_t = \beta_t - \beta_1 \;\;\forall\, t \in \left\{2,\ldots,T\right\}.
$$
One could therefore consider something like

```r
alphas_hat3 <- m3$coef[1:n] - betas[1]
betas_hat3 <- m3$coef[(n+1):(n+T-1)] + betas[1]
betas <- betas[-1]
```

which, with your seeds, yields

```r
cor(alphas, alphas_hat3)^2
# 0.984594
cor(betas, betas_hat3)^2
# 0.98608
```

and the following plot
[image]

Other seeds also generate plots in which the estimated coefficients are more evenly spread around the identity line.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! If you have time, perhaps you could also help me with a related one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593605?